# William Tell shoots an apple at uniformly chosen angle

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Found this problem in Grimmett's probability book. I do not know how to properly start it, I tried a few approaches, however they yielded completely different results from what the author's result is.

> William Tell is a very bad shot. In practice, he places a small green
>   apple on top of a straight wall which stretches to infinity in both
>   directions. He then takes up position at a distance of one perch from
>   the apple, so that his line of sight to the target if perpendicular to
>   the wall. He now selects an angle uniformly at random from his entire
>   field of view and shoots his arrow in this direction. Assuming that
>   his arrow hits the wall somewhere, what is the distribution function
>   (cdf) of the horizontal distance (measured in perches) between the
>   apple and the point which the arrow strikes.

The main problem that I had with my approaches was that I did not seem to express correctly in terms of the angle, the distance between the apple and the place where the arrow lands.

Comment: I think $tan(\theta)=$ distance required/one perch? Where the angle $\theta$ is the between the perpendicular distance and the hypotenuse.

Comment: I tried with $tan(\theta)$ and got a horribly wrong answer. It might be that I am not integrating over the correct space. Would you be able to provide a solution please?

Answer (score 2):

It is given that the angle (say $\theta$) between the line of shot and the line joining William to the apple is such that $\theta\sim \text{unif}[-\pi/2,+\pi/2]$. The signed horizontal distance from the apple to the point at which the arrow strikes is just $d=\text{tan}(\theta)$, and the magnitude of the distance is just $|d|$. So, the $CDF$ for $|d|$ is just $F(x)=P(|d|\leq x)=P(x\geq \text{tan}\theta \geq -x)=(1/\pi)\int _{-\text{tan}^{-1}(x)}^{\text{tan}^{-1}(x)}d\theta=(2/\pi)\text{tan}^{-1}(x)$.