# Application of the change of random variable technique

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The following equation (in red box) is bugging me (I'm keeping the source to myself for now in case the following text does contain a mistake):

[image]

For those having difficulties visualizing images here is the equation:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}f(\theta)d\theta = \int_{g(0)}^{g(\pi/2)}\frac{f\left(g^{(-1)}(x)\right)}{g'\left(g^{(-1)}(x)\right)}dx\tag 1$$

The issues I have with this is that the LHS of the equation is simply $1$ - i.e. the integration over the support of the pdf.

On the other hand, it seems as though the idea behind the RHS is the [distribution of the transformed random variable](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/157/), i.e. the integration of the general formula derived from the application of the chain rule $f_Y(y)=F'_Y(y)=f_x (v(y))\cdot v'(y),$ which I would have pictured in this particular example as

[Corrections after the answer provided by Andrei Crisan!]

$$\begin{align}\require{enclose}F_X(x) &= \int_0^{x=\mathsf {tan}(\theta)}f_\theta\left(\mathsf{arctan}(x)\right)\cdot \lvert \mathsf{arctan}(x)'\rvert dx\\[2ex]
&=\color{red}{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_0^{x=\mathsf {tan}(\theta)}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\mathsf{arctan}(x)}\cdot \color{red}{\frac{1}{x^2+1} }dx\\[2ex]
&=\frac{\enclose{horizontalstrike}1 2}{\pi}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\left(\mathsf{arctan(x)}\right)^2}\mathsf{arctan(x)}\tag 2
\end{align}$$

$\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\text{which I am not sure is the cdf of the half-Cauchy distribution}}$ which is the cdf of the half-Cauchy, but it does show (in red) the [pdf of the half-Cauchy](http://statperson.com/Journal/StatisticsAndMathematics/Article/Volume3Issue2/3_2_8.pdf), i.e.

$$f_X(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$$

in the intermediate step.

Even simpler,

> Why is the author dividing on the RHS of eq.(1) instead of multiplying? And (for extra points) where is the mistake in my derivation of the hal-Cauchy cdf in eq.(2)?

Comment: This problem has already been solved here [link] (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2810103/561429). Try reading it and let me know if you still have any questions. The solution he gives is quite good and straight to the point

Comment: @AndreiCrisan Pretty cool, and simple! I still would like to know where I went wrong on my derivation above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

His derivation is correct. Let's look a bit at the *change of variable* that occurs there. He says that:
$$
x = tan(\theta) = g(\theta)
$$
If we differentiate $g$ we get:
$$
g^\prime(\theta) = \frac{1}{cos^2(\theta)} = 1 + tan^2(\theta) = 1 + g^2(\theta)
$$
Hence, if we replace $\theta = g^{-1}(x)$ in the equation above we get:
$$
g^\prime (g^{-1}(x)) = 1 + g^2(g^{-1}(x)) = 1 + x^2 \tag1
$$
In the integral now, namely in $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\theta)d\theta$ making the substitution $\theta = arctanx$ we get that $d\theta = \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$, hence:
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\theta)d\theta = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(g^{-1}(x))\cdot\frac{dx}{1+x^2}\tag2
$$

But, from $(1)$ we know that $g^\prime (g^{-1}(x)) = 1 + x^2$. Substituting this in $(2)$ yields:

$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\theta)d\theta = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(g^{-1}(x))}{g^\prime (g^{-1}(x))}dx
$$
which is the desired result.

Also, your mistake is that you said $f_{\theta}(arctan(x)) = arctan(x)$, which is wrong as $f_\theta$ is constant (and equal to $\frac{2}{\pi}$).

Comment: Very nice. Two things: It seems like my mistake was rather silly / careless - notice that I had placed $\frac{2}{\pi}$ in front of the integral, but I added the $\mathsf{arctan}(x)$ inside the integral because I had in mind the cdf. Your answer is excellent, but I fail to see what he is doing there: if he is integrating the pdf over the domain, the result is obviously $1.$ Why is he doing so? How is this helping him get to the half-Cauchy, as opposed to what I tried to do?

Comment: Well, in the last equation I wrote in the above answer, you will get that  $1  = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$. But as far as I can tell, he goes around circularly to find $g(x)$, and, indeed the *LHS* of his equation is indeed $1$. Your idea is good. I guess what he might want to say is that the only $g$ that satisfies that integral equation is the *half Cauchy* distribution. (I'm not sure this is actually true though)